What is the 'info type in Anchor?
In this code snippet:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AddToWhitelist<'info> { //etc...

Regarding 'info I understand that the ' is a Rust lifetime elision (I think...), but what is the info type. Why is info lower-cap if it's a generic type, and what struct (?) does it represent?

That's the Rust syntax as you mentioned. It's not elision as that means to avoid lifetime specific syntax from code when not necessary - Rust compiler understands what is the right lifetime at the place, see e.g., https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html
The lifetime is defined in lowercase as that's the Rust syntax pattern.
I assume the Anchor framework uses the term 'info as it's related (by naming) to AccountInfo Rust type used within Solana as name for type containing information about any Solana account (see definition in Solana program code https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.18.11/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L19)
You could use the name e.g., 'a in your anchor program, like pub struct AddToWhitelist<'a>, it will be correct for Rust syntax but the Account macro expects usage of the lifetime named 'info and thus compilation fails. In other words, in Anchor program you need to use the lifetime named 'info as a required pattern.

Great answer, thank you!

Great answer, but I'd add to the 'the ' is not elision' answer some info about what the ' actually does. I'm pretty sure ' is a lifetime, ie https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotation-syntax

the <'info> is called a "lifetime" in rust.
A lifetime is a construct the compiler (or more specifically, its borrow checker) uses to ensure all borrows are valid.  In this case this is a lifetime to ensure that the struct AddtoWhiteList does not persist beyond info (anchor)
